# how to solve POST401directline.postActivity error occure on bot framework emulator?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots

I dont want to use "Azure bot service".
I have host bot application to azure, after that got hosted url https://something.azurewebsites.net then  registered a bot in bot framework https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new with https://something.azurewebsites.net/api/messages endpoint url, microsoft id and password.
I got microsoft Id and password when I create a new registration in app registration  on azure portal, 
Then I used that same Microsoft Id and password in visual studio code and republished.
But while testing on bot framework test emulator it shows "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue."  and  when I am trying on local bot framework emulator with microsoft app Id and password it shows "Cannot post activity. Unauthorized. POST401directline.postActivity"
I am using "bot framework" : 3.9 and ".net framework": 4.6

[Test on bot framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeUok.png)

[Test on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJqfh.png)

[Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdfrc.png)

[App registartion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spmyo.png)

Comment: Are you failing the https (secure) connection using TLS/SSL; or failing the login?

Comment: Sorry, i am not getting you , which type of login you are asking?

Comment: The login shown on the Setting link.

Comment: while testing in localhost, don,t add microsoftID and password , just remove from env/resource file and test, it worked for me also check it should be https

Answer (score 1):

**V3 of Bot Framework SDK is deprecated. It is recommended to use V4.**
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/master/README.md

Regarding this:

- > then registered a bot in bot framework
  >   https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new with
  >   https://something.azurewebsites.net/api/messages endpoint url,
  >   microsoft id and password.

and

- > I got microsoft Id and password when I create a new registration in
  >   app registration on azure portal

**These are redundant steps**. Really, what you should be doing is creating a `Bot Channels Registration` in the Azure portal or using `az bot` CLI.

> I dont want to use "Azure bot service

*This does not make sense*. Can you further explain what you mean by this? Those two steps you did above are doing exactly that; creating a `Bot Channels Registration`. "*Typical*" bots are two parts; a `Bot Channels Registration` (to allow connection to your bot from multiple places, take care of authentication, etc) and a web application (your bot code). Which one do you ***not*** want to use?

Regarding the emulator/authentication configuration:

I'm sure you know this, but I wanted to confirm that you are aware of the behavior of appid/password in a bot. Also for the benefit of others that might not be.

You can test with the emulator against a localhost running bot or a deployed bot. When testing with a localhost bot, you can test with appid/password or without. If you test without, you must make sure that they are not configured in the appsettings.json (in v4. other versions, etc. may use different configuration types) and not supplied in launching the bot in emulator. If you test with; you must configure in the appsettings.json **and** supply them when launching the bot in emulator.

Now let's move on to testing the online/deployed bot. In a deployed bot, it will either pick up the appid/password in the appsettings.json or from configuration in the Web App/App Service's settings. These settings must be titled `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword`.

So...all this being said, my *assumption* is that you created two applications (AAD app), and might be mixing up the appid/password. Either that, or it is not quite configured correctly in the Web app (https://something.azurewebsites.net); either in configuration file or in configuration settings in Azure.

I do hope this helps.